# Python: Filling a list from another list

Tags: python, list

I am trying create a new list ("newList") from items an existing list ("letterList").
The catch is, the the new list may start on any item in the existing list, depending on the argument passed to the function ("firstLetter"):

```
def makeNewList(firstLetter):
    letterList=["A","B","C"]
    newList=[]

    # get index of argument (firstLetter) 
    for i in [i for i,x in enumerate(letterList) if x==firstLetter]:
        index=i

    # fill newList from cycling through letterList starting at index position 
    for j in range(10):
        if index==3:
            index=0
        newList[j]=letterList[index]
        index=index+1
```

makeNewList("B")

I was hoping this would give me newList["B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A"] but I get
   IndexError: list assignment index out of range
referencing this line: newList[j]=letterList[index]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.append` function to add to the end of a list.

```
def makeNewList(firstLetter):
    letterList=["A","B","C"]
    newList=[]

    # get index of argument (firstLetter) 
    for i in [i for i,x in enumerate(letterList) if x==firstLetter]:
        index=i

    # fill newList from cycling through letterList starting at index position 
    for j in range(10):
        if index==3:
            index=0
        newList.append( letterList[index] )
        index=index+1
    return newList

print(makeNewList("B"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign by index to a list index that doesn't yet exist:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l[0] = "foo"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    l[0] = "foo"
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Instead, `append` to the end of `newList`. Also, you need to `return` the result:

```
def makeNewList(firstLetter):
    letterList=["A","B","C"]
    newList=[]

    # get index of argument (firstLetter) 
    for i in [i for i,x in enumerate(letterList) if x==firstLetter]:
        index=i

    # fill newList from cycling through letterList starting at index position 
    for j in range(10):
        if index==3:
            index=0
        newList.append(letterList[index]) # note here
        index=index+1

    return newList # and here
```

Here is a more Pythonic implementation:

```
def make_new_list(first_letter, len_=10, letters="ABC"):
    new_list = []
    start = letters.index(first_letter)
    for i in range(start, start+len_):
        new_list.append(letters[i % len(letters)])
    return new_list
```